# React Formik form: text area that allows users to select p and h tag

Tags: reactjs, textarea, formik

If I want to allow users to complete a text area and use a basic heading and paragraph styling on their input (sort of like medium), is there a utility that allows this feature to be built into a formik text area (so that user selections on paragraph breaks are respected?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? From what you've given, what I can think of is [react-medium-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-medium-editor)